# Value in javascript console not the same as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

When running the below function in chrome I can not figure out why the value of typing in the equation into the console is different from the terminal value of the array yearlyp, since yearlyp is being pushed that same equation, I also noticed that yearlyp never has negitive results when it should. Why does this happen? All the other variables outside the function are static.

```
((revenue * margin) * total_customer) - ((leadr * lead) + (lead * (hours * hr)))

15644.809809408005

yearlyp

[9891, 17803.8, 24134.04, 29198.232000000004, 33249.585600000006, 36490.66848, 39083.534784, 41157.82782720001, 42817.26226176001, 44144.809809408005]
```

here is the function:

```
   function cgr() {
total_customer = 0;
TCC = [];
yearlyp = [];
years = [];
for (year1 = 0; (churn * total_customer) < ((leadr * closing) - 0.9); year1++) {
        if ((churn * total_customer) >= (leadr * closing)) {
            final = year1;
        } else {
        total_customer = (total_customer + (leadr * closing)) - (churn * total_customer);
        yearlyp.push((revenue * margin) * total_customer) - ((leadr * lead) + (lead * (hours * hr)));
        years.push(year1);
        TCC.push(total_customer);
        console.log("total customer = " + total_customer + " |churn * total customer = " + (churn * total_customer) + " |leadr * closing =  " + (leadr * closing) + " |year = " + year1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What are the disparaging values? What specific values have you tried and what were their results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not pushing what you think you are. You're missing some parentheses. Your push is actually:

```
yearlyp.push((revenue * margin) * total_customer) - 
  ((leadr * lead) + (lead * (hours * hr)));
```

That is, you're just pushing the first part of the equation, then doing some math, subtracting 
that from whatever `push()` returns, and throwing that result away.

You mean to say:

```
yearlyp.push( 
  ((revenue * margin) * total_customer) - 
  ((leadr * lead) + (lead * (hours * hr))) 
);
```

(note the extra set of parentheses).